Failed to implement send confirmation email functionality
I use form to verify the email with emailjs, sending the email value to next.js API. In the API route.js I create and hash token, store it in database and make a confirmation link(so far the console.logs are giving my that everything is ok) and then in the sendEmail (which I use in another form and it works)function I receive: "Email send failed: undefined
portfolio3d-nextjs-app-1  | Failed to send email: Error: Failed to send email
portfolio3d-nextjs-app-1  |     at sendEmail (webpack-internal:".
Another info I use Docker image to run my project.
Can someone give me advice how to solve this problem?


'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Toaster, toast } from 'sonner';
import { MailCheck, MailX } from 'lucide-react';

export default function EmailConfirmationForm() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm();

    // Send confirmation email
    const handleSendConfirmationEmail = async (email) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/sendConfirmationEmail?email=${email}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
            });
            if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to send confirmation email');
            toast.success('Confirmation email sent!', {
                duration: 5000,
                icon: <MailCheck />,
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: '#1B1B1B',
                    border: 'none',
                },
            });
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error('Failed to send confirmation email.', {
                duration: 5000,
                icon: <MailX />,
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: '#1B1B1B',
                    border: 'none',
                },
            });
            return false;
        }
    };

    const onSubmit = async (data) => {

        try {
            await handleSendConfirmationEmail(data.email);

            reset(); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to send confirmation email:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Toaster position="bottom-left" richColors />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="max-w-md w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-4">

                {/* Email input */}
                <label htmlFor="email" className="self-start">Email Confirmation</label>
                <input
                    id="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Email Confirmation"
                    {...register("email", {
                        required: 'This field is required',
                        pattern: { value: /^\S+@\S+$/i, message: 'Invalid email format' }
                    })}
                    className="w-full p-2 rounded-md shadow-lg text-foreground focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-accent/50 custom-bg"
                    aria-label="Email"
                />
                {errors.email && <span className="inline-block self-start text-red-500">{errors.email.message}</span>}

                <input
                    value="Cast your message!"
                    className="px-10 py-4 rounded-md shadow-lg bg-background border border-accent/30 hover:shadow-glass-sm backdrop-blur-sm text-foreground focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-accent/50 cursor-pointer capitalize"
                    type="submit"
                />
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { sendEmail } from '@/app/../../service/service.email';
import redisClient, { connectRedis } from '@/app/../../service/redisClient';
import { generateToken, hashToken } from '@/app/../../service/tokenService';
import { rateLimiter } from '@/app/../../service/rateLimiter';

export async function POST(req) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
    const email = searchParams.get('email');
    const ip = req.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') || req.socket.remoteAddress || req.ip;

    // if (!rateLimiter(ip)) {
    //     return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Too many requests, please try again later.' }, { status: 429 });
    // }

    await connectRedis();

    const token = generateToken();
    const hashedToken = await hashToken(token);

    const expiresAt = Date.now() + 3600 * 1000;

    try {
        await redisClient.setEx(`confirm_tokens:${hashedToken}`, 3600, JSON.stringify({ email, expiresAt }));
        const storedToken = await redisClient.get(`confirm_tokens:${hashedToken}`);
        console.log('Token stored in Redis:', storedToken); // Log to verify storage
    } catch (redisError) {
        console.error('Error saving token in Redis:', redisError);
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error saving confirmation token to Redis.' }, { status: 500 });
    }

    const confirmationLink = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/api/confirmEmail?token=${token}&email=${email}`;
    console.log(`Confirmation link: ${confirmationLink}`);
    try {
        const templateParams = {
            to: email,
            from_name: 'Email Confirmation',
            reply_to: email,
            message: `Please confirm your email by clicking the link: ${confirmationLink}`,
        };

        await sendEmail(templateParams);

        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Confirmation email sent!' }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to send email:', error);
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Failed to send confirmation email.' }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const sendEmail = async (params) => {
    try {
        const response = await emailjs.send(
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVICE_ID,
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEMPLATE_ID,
            params,
            {
                publicKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUBLIC_KEY,
                limitRate: {
                    throttle: 5000,
                },
            }
        );
        console.log('Email sent successfully:', response);
        return response;  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Email send failed:', error.text);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Error response from email service:', error.response);
        }
        throw new Error(error.text || 'Failed to send email');
    }
};




I think you are using this node package on server side '@emailjs/browser'. while this is used for client side only.
please use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emailjs/nodejs on server side code.

The package looks like it is being run on the server.

Thanks, Riyaz Panarwala, you are right that emailjs is causing the problem. I read more about it and it looks like: "EmailJS has restrictions on server-side requests, as it's intended for use in browser environments where requests come from client-side code." and "One potential workaround is to create a serverless function on a platform like Vercel or Netlify that interacts with EmailJS via client-side code" looks too much to me. Think I'll use Nodemailer instead.
p.s. Your answer saved me few days reading and headache, Thankyou!

EmailJs expects a specific format. Try updating the key value pairs as follows:
to_email: email, 
from_name: 'Email Confirmation',
to_name: email.split('@')[0],  
message: `Please confirm your email by clicking the link: ${confirmationLink}`

change "to" to "to_email" and set "reply_to" to "to_name".
If this doesnt work, make sure your environment variables are properly set in docker and also consider adding logging to help debug errors.
